# Handling multiple navigation bar in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a top navigation bar in my index.html page. Within my main app I also have a mini app. When a user clicks "App2" on nav bar ideally i want the top navbar to be hidden and show a new side bar. Now to go back to "App1" I have a button which when clicked hides the side bar and starts showing the top bar.

I tried using ng-show/hide but problem is since the index.html pages loads only once the hide/show works only for the first time (page load).

```
Index.html 
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" ng-hide="value>
....
</nav>
</div>

app.js

MainCtrl
//just checks the value once 
$scope.value = $location.path();

if ($scope.value == any_path_in_app1) 
$scope.value = false; 
else 
$scope.value = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using 2 apps, then depending on the architecture of them you may need a third one or implements something in vanilla javascript or jquery.

I mean, if you have 2 apps, `angular.module('App1')` and `angular.module('App2')`, then if `App2` is a sibling app not a child app you won't be able to handle `ng-hide` or `ng-show` by treating it on `App1`. If that's the case, create an `AppManager` who treat the navigation being `App1` and `App2` parent.